# How to know the property value in Open Office Java API

Tags: java, api, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

To use the XPropertySet's `setPropertyValue()` method I need to know the arguments to be passed inside the method.
For e.g., to underline a Text in OpenOffice Writer I use `xTextProps.setPropertyValue("CharUnderline", com.sun.star.awt.FontUnderline.BOLD);` which underlines the text, Similarly the want to know the names of all the properties like **CharUnderline**, so as to perform other tasks in OpenOffice Writer.
How do I know the names of these properties. 
Pls suggest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The properties of a text object are listed here

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Formatting

"CharFontName", "CharFontStyleName", "CharFontFamily", "com.sun.star.awt.FontFamily", "CharFontCharSet", "com.sun.star.awt.CharSet", "CharFontPitch", "com.sun.star.awt.FontPitch", "CharColor", "CharEscapement", "CharHeight", "CharUnderline", "com.sun.star.awt.FontUnderline", "CharWeight", "com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight", "CharPosture", "com.sun.star.awt.FontSlant", "CharAutoKerning", "CharBackColor", "CharBackTransparent", "CharCaseMap", "com.sun.star.style.CaseMap", "CharCrossedOut", "CharFlash", "CharStrikeout", "com.sun.star.awt.FontStrikeout", "CharWordMode", "CharKerning", "CharLocale", "com.sun.star.lang.Locale", "CharKeepTogether", "CharNoLineBreak", "CharShadowed", "CharFontType", "com.sun.star.awt.FontType", "CharStyleName", "CharContoured", "CharCombineIsOn", "CharCombinePrefix", "CharCombineSuffix", "CharEmphasis", "com.sun.star.text.FontEmphasis", "CharRelief", "RubyText", "RubyAdjust", "RubyCharStyleName", "RubyIsAbove", "CharRotation", "CharRotationIsFitToLine", "CharScaleWidth", "HyperLinkURL", "HyperLinkTarget", "HyperLinkName", "VisitedCharStyleName", "UnvisitedCharStyleName", "CharEscapementHeight", "CharNoHyphenation", "CharUnderlineColor", "Color", "CharUnderlineHasColor", "CharStyleNames", "CharHidden", "TextUserDefinedAttributes", "XNameContainer"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16757775)

Comment: @JohnMoutafis Fixed it

Comment: I will retract my flag.

Comment: No, although I do believe that @Alok needs something different as an answer.

Comment: Joey it's possibly a system downvote. The system flags potential bad answers. Once edited the system marks that flag as helpful and throws a downvote. [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236883/community-downvotes-posts-that-were-just-fixed)

Comment: @Alok did this answer your question?